# When can you use "as soon as something will"?

Tags: grammar, future-tense, time-words

I used to think that you can't use will with "as soon as", however, in a NY times article I've encountered the following text:

> Asked what she wants to do now, Gul Meena says that all she wants is to return to her family. “I will go as soon as you will take me,” she said to Ms. Naderi.

Comment: Why did you think you can't use "as soon as" with "will"?  Also, there are two "wills" in that sentence, which one is confusing for you?

Comment: We usually don't use "as soon as *noun* will *verb*" because *will verb* means "in the future".  But "as soon as" means "at that point in the future".  At that point in the future, it's not a hypothetical or future possibility anymore, it's real.

Answer (score 1):

When "will" is used to indicate future tense, it's inappropriate to include it when following a construction indicating a future condition. However, in this case, "will" can be interpreted as indicating a future willingness: "I will go as soon as you are willing to take me".

Comment: Thank you very much!
What would you say about this sentence: "Obviously, a comparison of full individual genomes will be of interest as soon as this will be possible."?

Comment: @ppp7777 - No, the same thing applies.  We would say "It will be of interest as soon as it *is* possible."